# ¿Cómo obtener n documentos aleatorios no repetidos de Mongo con Mongoose?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

se me ocurre hacer peticiones individuales de documentos aleatorios hasta completar el número `n` deaseado de documentos, ***pero también necesito filtrarlas por un campo***.

Según, así sería aleatorio (según mis confirmaciones esto siempre devuelve el mismo documento por paginación):

```
Model.find()
.limit(3)
.skip(2)
.then(preguntas => {
    res.send(preguntas);
})
.catch(err => {
    res.status(500).send({
        message: err.message || "Some error occurred while retrieving notes."
    });
});
```

Luego, podría hacer peticiones en el front hasta obtener lo que quiero... ¿Pero no hay una mejor forma? Digo, he leído que ese trabajo es mejor dejarselo a la base de datos porque regularmente está optimizada para ciertos procesos.

He leído soluciones que satisfacen la cantidad pero no un filtro, algo como:

> Traer 10 preguntas aleatorias no repetidas de tipo "fácil".

Una ayuda, por favor.

Answer (score 0):

En mongoDB >= 3.2. existe el [operador $sample](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sample/) Que permite hacer justamente esto.

Este ejemplo devuelve 3 usuarios al azar:

```
db.users.aggregate(
   [ { $sample: { size: 3 } } ]
)
```

Aún así, hay que tener en cuenta que $sample **puede devolver documentos repetidos**. Así que una opción sería hacer un sample de 1, y repetirlo el numero de veces que necesites añadiendo en el $match de los siguientes que él id de la pregunta **no sea ninguno de los anteriores**. Así en cada petición te devolverá una pregunta distinta a las anteriores y totalmente aleatoria.

Espero pueda servirte de ayuda!